# mvc modal looses its styling when submit fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a section on a parent form that is declared as Modal. Initially, the modal displays as expected, however, after I press my submit button on the form it hits my mvc controller method post as expected. Within the controller, an error may get occur and at that point I add an error to my models alert property and return the view. The form and error display, but it seems to have lost all styling. The modal is initially shown as a render partial, but in the controller I was returning it as a view instead of a partialview so thought that might be the issue, but that didn't make any difference. So next, I thought that it's because the main stylesheet that the modal needs is declared on the parent, and because I'm using a modal, it might be on coming back that the stylesheet is no longer referenced, So I explicitly referenced the stylesheet in the modal, but that too has made no difference. I'm now at a bit of a lose as to what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The View is rendered after the GET action calls it.  Bootstrap modal is used.  Within the modal, there is a submit button that calls the POST, and the controller action, marked HTTPPost is called.  After the post, the styling is reapplied.

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index12</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .keepStyle {
            background-color: antiquewhite;
            font: italic small-caps bold 44px Georgia, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    @*https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/*@
    <div class="keepStyle">This div style remains after postback</div>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
    </button>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">(Post)Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index12()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index12(int? id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This would be better with an explanation of what's going on. It's really hard to tell if this answers the question asked.